# run artisan queue:work on dynamic multitenant multi database system

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan, laravel-queue

I'm using laravel 8, and developed a multitenant app in laravel.

My application created different database dynamically for each user
and database connection is based on subdomain.
for say if the subdomain is `foo.example.com` it connects with the database `foo`

I have a list of all subdomain in an array.

Now I want to run php artisan queue:work or execute the jobs table task for every subdomain / database. if i's not possible with artisan command i am open to any other hacks.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by either using different [connections or queues](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#connections-vs-queues). When using different queues, you still manage all of the jobs on the same backend service. If you want to use a different backend service (or multiple backend services of the same type) you should probably go for multiple connections.

## Using multiple queues

[Dispatch](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#dispatching-to-a-particular-queue) your jobs with `->onQueue($currentSubdomain)`.
[Start](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#specifying-the-connection-queue) your queue workers with `php artisan queue:work --queue=<foo>`, where `<foo>` is your current subdomain.

## Using multiple connections

[Dispatch](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#dispatching-to-a-particular-connection) your jobs with `->onConnection($currentSubdomain)`.
[Start](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#specifying-the-connection-queue) your queue workers with `php artisan queue:work <connection>`.

**Note**: Using multiple connections needs proper configuration in your `queue.php`. The easiest way would be to just use multiple queues, as for them no additional configuration is needed.